# Can not copy file on web page

Tags: python, file-copying

I have a python script on web page that should open one "gnuplot.gp" file and copy its content to my "final.gp" But it does not work. I have all things set up right.

Code:

```
file = open('gnuplot.gp','r')
plot = file.read()
file.close()


file = open('final.gp','w+')
file.write('%s' %plot)
file.close()
```

Comment: Can you just use [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)?

Comment: at a guess that user does not have permission to create a file wherever you are running this ...

Comment: Something to do with the fact file contains binary data? Why not just `file.write(plot)` ?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I edited it to file.write(plot) my bad sorry :D  But it still not working... I also set chmod of both files to 777, script too. CGI scripts are also enabled. I don't know what to do :/

- I need to do some substitution so thats why I save it to the variable for a while.

Comment: You need to tell us what is not working.

Comment: "is not working" is possibly the most useless description of a problem. Please describe exactly in which way it "doesn't work".

Comment: Works for me. Must be permissions or something like Joran mentioned

Comment: I know that it is bad description but I do not have acces to error log... It should work but "final.gp" is still empty..  after i run the script...

Comment: Can you try writing just some string? `file.write('Blah')`

Comment: Did you try 'rb' and 'wb' instead of 'r' and 'w+'?

Answer (score 0):

There is two things to try. One, is this (which is not a very reliable method due to file size issues);

```
file = open('gnuplot.gp','r')
plot = file.read()
file.close()


file = open('final.gp','w')
file.write(plot)
file.close()
```

Or, the other is, as others suggested, `shutil`.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('gnuplot.gp','final.gp')
```

Of course, this is all assuming you have permissions. If you get `[Access Denied]`, you'll either need to delete `final.gp`, and then copy, and/or make sure the destination directory or `gnuplot.gp` is not read only. If you get an empty file after trying the first method, that is because python can't handle many file types, so `shutil` would be the way to go.